# Developer machine for SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am going to setup a sharepoint farm for development purpose. Can anyone tell me what type of SharePoint edition i should go for? i mean if company has more than 5 sharepoint devs, what version they choose/?

I know there are only 3 versions available and no developer edition available.

Should i use foundation? if not why?

Should go for Standard? or enterprise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint 2013 come with 3 editions

- SharePoint 2013 Foundation
- SharePoint 2013 Standard
- SharePoint 2013 Enterprise

Basically, it depends on upon your requirement, what you want to develop. If development is for the enterprise level services i.e excel, powerpoint etc then you should install the SharePoint ent edition. it also depends what version of SharePoint you are using in Production.

If you are using SharePoint foundation in Production but You build a solution in SharePoint server environment then chances are that solution will not work.

Check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee554869.aspx

Comment: So there is no specific criteria as such and it all depends on what you want. i was just wondering what people choose when they have 100 SharePoint dev. obviously Enterprise is not a good option here with the cost involved and not foundation either.

Comment: Yes it all about the requirement, But if you have the MSDN subscription then SharePoint is free for development.

Comment: free for development meaning? you get all the onpremise setups for SharePoint?

Comment: Yes, if you have the MSDN subscription or your company owns a subscription then you will get copy of Software for testing / development purpose but not for production.

Comment: As part of your MSDN subscription, you also get a monthly Azure credit which makes development a lot easier by providing SharePoint VM's you can quickly deploy for development and testing purposes.